# Finding the row value of one column based on closest value of another colum in dataframe

Tags: r, mean, binning

I am trying to get the closest value of a column corresponding to another column in a df. example below to illustrate:

I have dataframe `df`:

```
df <- as.data.frame(dnorm(c(1:100), 50))
df$"bin" <- 1:100
```

What `"bin"` would be closest to correspond to lets say the mean of `dnorm(c(1:100), 50)`.

```
df$bin[df$`dnorm(c(1:100), 50)` == max(df$`dnorm(c(1:100), 50)`)]
$ [1] 50


df$bin[df$`dnorm(c(1:100), 50)` == mean(df$`dnorm(c(1:100), 50)`)]
$ integer(0)
```

any input is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We could take the `abs` difference of the column with the `mean` and get the index of `min` of that difference

```
set.seed(24)
df1 <- data.frame(bin = 1:100, col1 = dnorm(c(1:100), 50))
v2 <- with(df1, abs(col1  - mean(col1)))
df1$bin[v2 == min(v2)]
[1] 47 53
```